# How to properly use MaterialComponents Theme on my App?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, material-components-android

I recently switched from AppCompat to MaterialComponents on my theme, because i wanted the benefits that the styling would bring to my TextInputLayout. But whenever I add it to my project the Layout vanishes.
Goes Blank, The layouts show on my phone when I run the code, just not on the editor

So far I've tried: 
Refreshing the Layout,
Clicking Show Layout Decorations,
Building, cleaning the project, and
Invalidating cache and restarting...

This is the theme I'm using

```
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
```

this is for my TextInputLayout

```
    <style name="Widget.InputLayout.TextInputLayout" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">
        <item name="hintTextAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.InputLayout.TextInputLayout.HintText</item>
        <item name="hintTextColor">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:paddingBottom">8dp</item>
        <item name="boxStrokeColor">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    </style>

    <style name="TextAppearance.InputLayout.TextInputLayout.HintText" parent="TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Subtitle2">
        <item name="android:textColor">?android:attr/textColorPrimary</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: kotlin_version = '1.3.41'  *** material_version = "1.1.0-alpha08"

Comment: For now use stable material design version: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56590920/7254873